# Partially retaining value and conditionally replacing observation's value

Tags: hash, sas, retain

The data-set looks like this:

```
Server  IP          Indicator Session_ID   Time
2      1.20.54.221              A           00:00:01
2      1.20.54.221              A           00:01:00
1      1.20.54.221  Site        A           00:02:00
1      1.20.54.221              B           00:05:00
2      1.20.54.221  Site        B           00:08:00
2      1.20.54.221              C           00:10:00
2      1.20.54.221              C           00:15:00
1      1.20.54.221              F           01:00:00
1      1.20.54.221              F           01:05:00
2      1.20.54.221  Site        F           01:08:00
```

The above data set is read from a log file. `Session_id` will change when the server changes ( i.e. `1` -> `2` or `2` -> `1` ). There are cases where the server changes right after a change occurred (i.e. `1`---->`2`----->`1`). Whenever a server is changed, the server would record the last `Session_id` and return a new `Session_id` at its second browse of the same server. ( e.g. 3rd observation : `Session_id` still `A`, and changed to `B` for 4th observation) . If the server changes in the way (i.e. `1`---->`2`----->`1`---->`1`), it will return `A`-----> `A`----->`B`---> `C`, in which `B` is generated by server `2` and `C` is generated by the second `1`

My objective is to determine whether there is subgroup(s) among records. The rule is :

> Given the same IP, If the time difference between the current record and last record does not exceed 30 minutes, 
>   then the record belongs to the same user.

I have an indicator variable `site` to determine whether the site has changed. It is marked based on whether the change of server happens and the time difference is less than 30 mins.

**Desired data set:**

```
Server  IP          Indicator Session_ID   Time           Difference  Last_site 
2      1.20.54.221              A           00:00:01       .            .
2      1.20.54.221              A           00:01:00       59s          .
1      1.20.54.221  Site        A           00:02:00       1 Min        .
1      1.20.54.221              A           00:05:00       3 Min        Site
2      1.20.54.221  Site        A           00:08:00       3 Min        Site
2      1.20.54.221              A           00:10:00       2 Min        Site
2      1.20.54.221              A           00:15:00       5 Min        Site
1      1.20.54.221              F           01:00:00       45min         . 
1      1.20.54.221              F           01:05:00       5 Min         .
2      1.20.54.221  Site        F           01:08:00       3 Min         .
```

**My implementation:**

```
data log_file;
set log;
retain _Session_id Last_site;,

* Assign value to retain ; 
if indicator = "Site" then _Session_id = Session_id;

* if last_site = Site, its value has to be changed;
last_site=lag(site); 

* Record that should be in another group ;
if difference >30 then Last_Site = "";  

* Replace;
if last_site  not eq "" then session_id = _session_id 

run;
```

And the problem is, the `retained variable` will change from `A` to `B` at the fifth observation, while I would like to have it stick to the value `A` until I found a record with time difference greater than `30` mins. ( the process would loop over hundred thousands of IP and therefore efficiency is also concerned.)

Is there a possible way to handle the problem elegantly? 
Thank you in advance.

**[ Edited on 22/6]**

I am thinking the possibility of using Hash Object to do the job. I wrote some codes (obviously they does not work and may incur syntax error ).

```
data test11a;
length mark $ 12 ip $ 32 Session_id $ 200 agent last_agent $ 200; <== the system said there is error with the type of variable and therefore I add this
Declare hash hid;   
hid = _new_ hash( ordered : ' ascending');
hid.definekey('ip');
hid.definedata('Session_id');
hid.definedone();
call missing ( ip, Session_id);
   do while ( not done);
    set test11 end=done; <==== I have the original data-set called test11
    by ip notsorted ; <==== hash object by group;
    if not first.ip or not last.ip then do;
       if mark = "Site" then rc=  hid.add();
      *if mark = "Next_Group" then hid.remove(key : ip); <=== Error
    end;
    if mark not eq "Site" or "Next_Group" then do;
      rc=hid.find();  <==== Find matching iP and if matching ( rc=0)
      * use variable _ session_id to test;
      if rc = 0 then _session_id = Session_id;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

And the output data set has only two observations. Anyone could help to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, as I could not figure out how you construct 'Last_site'. Seems to me what you want is to check whether the difference is over 30 mins/1800 sec, if 'no', the session_id stays the same, if 'yes', it adopts a new session_id. I may have oversimplified your problem, but the outcome seems close:

```
data have;
    input (Server  IP          Indicator Session_ID) (:$20.)   Time :time8.;
    format time time8.;
    cards;
2      1.20.54.221  .            A           00:00:01
2      1.20.54.221   .           A           00:01:00
1      1.20.54.221  Site        A           00:02:00
1      1.20.54.221    .          B           00:05:00
2      1.20.54.221  Site        B           00:08:00
2      1.20.54.221     .         C           00:10:00
2      1.20.54.221      .        C           00:15:00
1      1.20.54.221       .       F           01:00:00
1      1.20.54.221        .      F           01:05:00
2      1.20.54.221  Site        F           01:08:00
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by ip notsorted;
    retain _session ' ';

    if first.ip then
        _session=session_id;
    difference=dif(time);

    if  difference > 1800 then
        _session=session_id;
    drop session_id;
    rename _session=session_id;
run;
```